# Locate files which ONLY contain printable characters in bash script

Tags: bash, grep, non-printable

I'm trying to write a bash script that looks at a directory full of files and categorises them as either plaintext or binary.  A file is plaintext if it ONLY contains plaintext characters, otherwise it is binary.  So far I have tried the following permutations of grep:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=`ls`
for i in $FILES
do
    ########GREP SYNTAX###########
    if grep -qv -e[:cntrl:] $i
    ########/GREP SYNTAX##########
    then
        mv $i $i-plaintext.txt
    else
        mv $i $i-binary.txt
    fi
done
```

In the grep syntax line, I have also tried the same without the -v flag and swapping the branches of the if statements, as well as both combinations of the same with [:alnum:] and [:print:].   All six of these variations produce some files labelled binary wich consist solely of plantext and some files labelled plaintext which contain at least one non-printable character.

I need to find a way to identify files that **only** contain printable characters i.e. A-Z, a-z, 0-9, punctuation, spaces and new lines.  All files containing any character that is not in this set shoudl be classified as binary.

I've been bashing my head against a wall trying to sort this for half a day.
Help!
Thanks in advance,
Rik

Comment: Did you try the command `file`?

Comment: @eumiro: You can get false results since that doesn't look at the whole file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you can/should do

```
for f in *
```

instead of putting the output of `ls` in a variable. The chief reason for doing this is to be able to handle filenames that include spaces.

Second, you need to enclose the character class in a set of brackets or it's going to look at those characters as literals. And I would enclose them in a set of single quotes to protect against the shell interpreting them. Don't use `-v` and negate the `print` class and see if that works for you.

```
if grep -aq -e '[^[:print:]]' "$f"
```

And as shown in that line, always quote variables when they contain filenames.

```
mv "$f" "$f-plaintext.txt"
```

To keep `grep` from complaining about binary files, use `-a`.

The variable `i` is often used for an integer or an index. Use `f` or `file`.

Finally:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *
do
    if grep -aq -e '[^[:print:]]' "$f"
    then
        mv "$f" "$f-binary.txt"
    else
        mv "$f" "$f-plaintext.txt"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the -I option of grep which will treat binary files as files without a match and just use a regex that will always match (like the empty string):

```
if grep -qI -e '' $i
```

Comment: Thanks for the response,That will only match files that are entirely

Comment: That will oly match files which are entirely binary, rather than files which are a mixture of binary and printable characters.